# Method 'GET' is not supported

Tags: javascript, java, http, exception

When I make `HTTP POST` request, I got this message on my screen. How can I solve this problem?  I don't use any `GET` annotation or request.

HTPP REQUEST : http://localhost:9000/user/register?username=a&password=1

Console Error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

JavaScript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("signupbtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:9000/user/register?username="+username+"&password="+password);
    xhr.send();
  })

</script>
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/register")
ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password) {
    userService.addUser(username, password);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("User added succesfully");
}
```

Service

```
public void addUser(String username,String password){
    userRepository.save(new User(username,password));
       
}
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. It's saying you are using GET, while the code shows POST. Use your browser console to find out what is actually happening.

Comment: No I m not using any get. I try to use POST. I just try to get username and password from the client and add into the database but Error meassage is about GET but I didnt use any GET

Comment: You wouldn't get that error unless *some* GET request is being done somewhere. Again, use your browser console to find out.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of the browser to see if the actual request being sent is GET or POST? The code shown here should send a POST request which doesn't explain the error message.

Comment: Console has just that error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: In ınternate says when you add or change something you need to use POST and  I need to these username and password to insert user  into database

Comment: WHY are you sending up the username and password in a querystring.... that is not secure, it should be in the body of the message...

Comment: "Console has just that error" OK, so you found the browser console. Now open the Network tab and do what @nickzoum said.

Comment: It s a just little project to understand and learn how the works going. Can you tell me how Can i send the body message and how to make it please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when i send to request. This is a GET request not POST . I changed the PostMapping To GetMapping problem is solved. I think there is missunderstanding about POST and GET mapping

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution from the [REQBIN](https://reqbin.com/code/javascript)

Please refer the link and execute the code and apply in your project

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json");

let data = {
  "Id": 78912,
  "Customer": "Jason Sweet",
};

xhr.onload = () => console.log(xhr.status);

xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code  , it should work unless you do have restriction in your app security config  like (allowedMethods )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).